# texdoc won't work

Tags: stata

I want to write sweave-a-like texts in Stata and try to do it by using the `texdoc` package.

I've updated all my packages but it doesn't seem to work fully.

Example:

```
* texdoc Init
texdoc init $texdoc/myexample.tex, replace

tex \documentclass{article}
tex \usepackage{stata}
tex \begin{document}

tex \section{First Things First}

tex So when i write it like this, it works like a charm \\

/*tex 
\section{Second things never}
But when i write it like this, nothing happens
tex*/

tex You wouldnt think this is possible

texdoc stlog
local w=99
dis "because 1+1=`w'" 
texdoc stlog close  

tex \end{document}

texdoc close
```

After "texdoc do filename" the tex document looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stata}
\begin{document}
\section{First Things First}
So when i write it like this, it works like a charm \\
You wouldnt think this IS possible

\begin{stlog}
    \input{myexample_1.log.tex}
    \end{stlog}

\end{document}
```

Why does it compile right when I put the code after the "tex" command, and why doesn't it if I put it between /*tex and tex*/?

I scanned the ado file and couldn't find anything wrong...

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue. Just to be clear, after writing the tex do-file (your first section of code), you save it somewhere and execute `texdoc do filename` to produce the .tex file, correct? I believe executing the tex block code inside of a Stata do-file will not behave as you desire. It needs to be executed with `texdoc do filename`, not with `do filename`, which is the result of executing straight from the do-file.

Comment: Of course i `texdoc do` the specified `*.texdoc`. Interestingly the document is processed just the same if i just type in `do *.texdoc`. Whats wrong with my packages? Can you process the "right" latex code in my example?

Comment: Its working now... it seems that theres something wrong with the global variable that i used to define my directory...

Comment: Interesting. Well, I'm glad to found your answer.